# How to add leading 0 to a simple countdown timer in angular

Tags: angular

I want to create a simple countdown timer in Angular. 
I want to format the timer with a leading zero, so bellow 10, 9 becomes 09, 8 - 08, etc. till 0 - 00.

I didn't find a built-in pipe. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: When you display the timer, it will be a string. Just add 0 in front

Comment: ```let timer = `${time < 10 ? 0 : ''}${time}`;``` where `time` is your counter

Answer (score 4):

Did you not try the `number` pipe??

```html
<div>{{ value | number:'2.0-0' }}</div>
```

The `2` here specifies the minimum number of integer digits.

The first `0` specifies the minimum number of fractional digits.

The second `0` specifies the maximum number of fractional digits.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vt2qeq